# C5.0 error saying models require a factor outcome

Tags: r, machine-learning

My data looks like this:

```
Age   Job House    Credit Loan.Approved
1   Young FALSE    No      Fair            No
2   Young FALSE    No      Good            No
3   Young  TRUE    No      Good           Yes
4   Young  TRUE   Yes      Fair           Yes
5   Young FALSE    No      Fair            No
6  Middle FALSE    No      Fair            No
7  Middle FALSE    No      Good            No
8  Middle  TRUE   Yes      Good           Yes
9  Middle FALSE   Yes Excellent           Yes
10 Middle FALSE   Yes Excellent           Yes
11    Old FALSE   Yes Excellent           Yes
12    Old FALSE   Yes      Good           Yes
13    Old  TRUE    No      Good           Yes
14    Old  TRUE    No Excellent           Yes
15    Old FALSE    No      Fair            No
```

This is the code I am trying to use to create a decision tree with this.

```
LoanDFrame$Job <- as.factor(LoanDFrame$Job)
tr <- C5.0(Loan.Approved ~ Age + Job + House + Credit, data = LoanDFrame)
```

I keep getting the error message saying models require a factor outcome.
Why does this keep happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

C5.0 expects the outcome to be a factor with 2 or more levels. You could make factor variables from all variables in this data frame and apply the algorithm.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(C50)


df <- structure(list(Age = c("Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", 
                             "Middle", "Middle", "Middle", "Middle", "Middle", "Old", "Old", 
                             "Old", "Old", "Old"), Job = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
                                                           FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE
                             ), House = c("No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", 
                                          "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No"), Credit = c("Fair", 
                                                                                                    "Good", "Good", "Fair", "Fair", "Fair", "Good", "Good", "Excellent", 
                                                                                                    "Excellent", "Excellent", "Good", "Good", "Excellent", "Fair"
                                          ), Loan.Approved = c("No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", 
                                                               "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No")), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                  "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -15L))
df <- df %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = everything(), factor))

tr <- C5.0(Loan.Approved ~ Age + Job + House + Credit, data = df)

summary(tr)
#> 
#> Call:
#> C5.0.formula(formula = Loan.Approved ~ Age + Job + House + Credit, data = df)
#> 
#> 
#> C5.0 [Release 2.07 GPL Edition]      Mon Nov 14 22:23:15 2022
#> -------------------------------
#> 
#> Class specified by attribute `outcome'
#> 
#> Read 15 cases (5 attributes) from undefined.data
#> 
#> Decision tree:
#> 
#> House = Yes: Yes (6)
#> House = No:
#> :...Job = FALSE: No (6)
#>     Job = TRUE: Yes (3)
#> 
#> 
#> Evaluation on training data (15 cases):
#> 
#>      Decision Tree   
#>    ----------------  
#>    Size      Errors  
#> 
#>       3    0( 0.0%)   <<
#> 
#> 
#>     (a)   (b)    <-classified as
#>    ----  ----
#>       6          (a): class No
#>             9    (b): class Yes
#> 
#> 
#>  Attribute usage:
#> 
#>  100.00% House
#>   60.00% Job
#> 
#> 
#> Time: 0.0 secs
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @Seth . The assignment wants us to do this without making a dataframe though? I have imported the csv file with the same data into R, so what would I do from there?

Comment: @roTenshi2 but your example data/code uses a dataframe?

Comment: @zephryl I mean as in not manually creating a dataframe using the table data.